# I have a logic error with the insertion into array

Tags: php, sql-server, arrays

I'm not very familiar with php, so I'm asking lot of questions because of this. I'm trying to insert multiple values into $logout array variable after getting values from database, but when i run the code, I got two arrays and each one have a value :

**Array ( [0] => 10:05:02 ) Array ( [0] => 15:03:30 )**

I need them in the single array, I don't know what goes wrong with my code, could any one help me with this point. This is my php array block code:

```
while( $Frow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Fstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    $R1 = $Frow['EmpID'];
    $R2 = $Frow['DATE']->format('Y-m-d');
    $R3 = $Frow['TIME']->format('H:i:s');
    $R4 = $Frow['OBJECT'];


    if (    $R4 == 1112 or $R4 == 2222)
    {

        /*$logout = array ("$R3");
        $count = count($logout);
        for ($x=0 ; $x<=$count; $x++){
        print_r ($logout[$x]);
        }*/

        $logout = array();
        $count = count($logout);
        for ($x=0 ; $x<=$count; $x++){
        //$logout = array($R3);
        $logout[$x] = $R3;
        //print_r ($logout); 
        }
        print_r ($logout); 


        /*$logout = array("$R3");
        foreach($logout as $key=>$value) {
        $logout = array($value);
        //print $value;
        ECHO "</BR>";
        print_r ($logout);
        ECHO "</BR>"; */

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are several mistakes:

In the code:

```
     $logout = array();
    $count = count($logout);
    for ($x=0 ; $x<=$count; $x++){
    //$logout = array($R3);
    $logout[$x] = $R3;
    //print_r ($logout); 
    }
    print_r ($logout);
```

you declare the value of variable $logout to be an array, then the value of variable $count will always be 0.

To meet your end, you should declare the variable $logout outside and before the wile loop, then add the new value at then end.

try:

```
$logout = arary();

while( $Frow = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $Fstmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

$R1 = $Frow['EmpID'];
$R2 = $Frow['DATE']->format('Y-m-d');
$R3 = $Frow['TIME']->format('H:i:s');
$R4 = $Frow['OBJECT'];


if (    $R4 == 1112 or $R4 == 2222)
{
    $logout[] = $R3;
}

}

    print_r ($logout);
```

Comment: THANK YOU Yang, i understand what you said, hope not to fall in the same mistake again, your solution solved my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of this:

`$logout = array();`

You are reinitializing it as a new array everytime. This is why your value is being printed but not together with the before. Declare that statement before your `while` loop.

Also you do not need a `for` loop inside and as @Rikesh has said, use `[]` to get auto-incremented index.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `$x` can be 0 each time your upper loops run, so just change that line to,

```
$logout[] = $R3;
```

And `print_r($logout);` after end of loops. And as @I Can Has Cheezburger [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497500/696364), declare your `$logout` array before your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `$logout = array();` either **before** *while loop* or *for loop* as per your logic.

You are having issue because `$logout` is declared inside the for loop and it is getting re-initialized every time loop iterate.

Comment: thank you, i declare it outside the loop and it worked